# How to add an image to a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, image

I'm currently working in Microsoft Visual Studio and I am doing a project for school where I have to make an app that lets you book seats at a cinema and see the description of the movie you have selected as well as leave/read a review.

In my app I have decided that I want to include pictures (basically a poster for each of the movies); I have made my `Movies` table and have `idf` as my primary key. I have added a `poster` column in my table definition and I have set its type to `image`.

My question is, how do I assign a certain image to a movie, so as to have access to it and to be able to display it later using a query of some sort?

Comment: adding image to the datanbase is not a good idea. just add the filename or path to the file

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani That's a wrong generalization. There are cases where it would make sense to store the images in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: Use `varbinary(MAX)` instead of `image`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all the `poster` column should be of type `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Then you can use the following `SELECT` to get the contents:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT poster FROM Movies WHERE IDF = @id", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idf", <The movie ID>);
    byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    // imageBytes is now either null or the bytes you stored in the column
}
```

The same goes for `INSERT` or `UPDATE`:

```
byte[] imageBytes = ...;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Movies (..., Poster) VALUES (..., @poster)", connection))
{
    // Other parameters
    ...

    // imageBytes contains a byte array representing the image
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poster", imageBytes);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I suggest you store the raw PNG/JPEG file bytes. First of all they are already compressed, secondly you can then easily use a `MemoryStream` to restore the image (search SO for how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Movies(poster) 
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img.
```

BulkColumn is syntax.